# Why last blog post excerpt is shown instead of meta description?

Tags: pages, description, google-search

[image]Instead of meta description of my main page Google shows excerpt from my last blog post. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the place for the [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

**But to answer your questions:**
Google trying to show the most relevant results based on what the search query is. This also includes the meta description. Google may choose to show another content on your page which is different than your meta description tag.

From **moz.com**

> Google's attempts to match snippets to queries don't always work the
>   way you'd like, but in general they're a good thing. Matching, bolded
>   keywords drive click-throughs, and people rarely read the whole text
>   of a snippet. If it’s just a couple of long-tail queries, don't worry
>   about it.